# Combining multiple excel files from folders based on excel spreadsheets without a certain heading

Tags: r, excel, heading

I am new to R. I have multiple Excel files in different folders that I would like to take out into a single file. All the files contain the same heading in row 2 except some have an extra heading (hierarchy). I would like to only take out and combine all the spreadsheets that exclude the Hierarchy heading.

Is there an easy way of doing this in R?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Can you give an example on how the two excel spreadsheets differ in more detail. Since then it would probably be possible to just select them based on the entries in the first imported row.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! My spreadsheets have a hierarchy order (eg separate excel docs for group, division, branch, team). I would like the docs where there is no hierarchy column (in row 2) in the spreadsheet (all of the sheets I would like to extract have data in columns B to Y). All other docs have more columns with data. Hopefully that makes things clearer. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is to get you started, but after the import you need filter out the wrong sheets, I can't do that, because the condition is not clear enough.

```
library(readxl)
library(data.table)
# Import single sheets for all excel files, which are found in the working directory
import.xlsx <- data.table(read_xlsx(path = list.files(path = ".", pattern = "\\.xlsx$")))

# Import all sheets in an Excel workbook
sheet_list <- lapply(excel_sheets( list.files(path = ".", pattern = "\\.xlsx$")), read_excel, path= list.files(path = ".", pattern = "\\.xlsx$"))
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for not making the condition clear enough. Is it possible after the import to filter out the docs that have a 'Hierarchy' header in the first row? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: You'll need to show me either how the excel header looks like or the imported `data.table`. Of course it's possible, but to be precise I need more information.

Comment: I was thinking and I think an easier way to go about my problem is to start with mapping a hierarchy and a top-down approach. Is there a way of to start docs where the size of the team is between 40-60. Then apply a condition where if you go down one further in the hierarchy, do you lose more than 1/3 of the responses? If so, then stop at the higher level. If not, then go down to the smaller teams. Please let me know if this doesn't make sense again...THANKS SO MUCH!

Comment: Note: the team size is always in cell E12-F12 (merged cell).

Comment: If there's a hierarchy you need to be able to identify these properly. This question is not specific enough to help you. Please provide some data on the names of the Spreadsheets, Worksheets and so on. Additionally, please recreate a dataset, with bogus data if it's sensitive data.

Comment: Hopefully this makes it clearer. http://imgur.com/KGskviw The image contains the first few rows from three separate excel files In hierarchy order (Branch X is lowest, Group X is highest level). I would like to use a kind of top-down approach and say what level is closest to 40 respondents? If this is not the lowest level (in this case Branch is lowest but Division is closest to 40) if you go down another level, how many respondents do you miss out on? If it's more than 1/3 because Branches are too small (less than 10 we don't have data) then stay at the Division level.

Comment: Sorry. Update. Starting from the top of the hierarchy, once you get to less than 50 respondents, stop. That's the 'team' level that I want. If it's more than 50, keep going down the 'tree' unless you lose more than 25-30% of respondents by doing so. If that's the case, stay at the higher level. Thanks!

Comment: Should I start by trying to make a hierarchy tree? There are a lot of excel files. Will that make is easier to move down the tree and determine teams of at least 50?

Comment: I would first try to import anything and do the hierarchy logic inside of R.